# Расчет доставки через 10 дней за исключением выходных

Tags: php

Помогите расчитать доставку через 10 дней за исключением выходных.

```
<?php 
function weekend ($date_my) {//дата типа: date("d.m.Y") или "19.02.2011"
                $weekend = date("w",strtotime($date_my));

                if($weekend==0 || $weekend==6) {
                    return  $weekend= date( "d-m-w-l",strtotime("$date_my+12day"));
                } else {
                    return  $weekend= date( "d-m-w-l",strtotime("$date_my+10day"));
                       }//1 выходной, 0 будни
}
echo weekend ('24.02.2018');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Данный функционал доступен в [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php) и записывается в формате *+n weekday*:

```
$time = time(); //Текущая дата в UNIX timestamp
$deliveryTimestamp = strtotime('+10 weekday', $time);
echo "Товар будет доставлен: " . 
      \DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $deliveryTimestamp)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Данный код предполагает, что доставка будет осуществлена **на 10 день**.

Предположим, если клиент сделает заказ **2018-03-03 в субботу**, то в данном случае доставка будет осуществлена в **пятницу 2018-03-16**.

Comment: спасибо большое!